# change url using jquery for specific css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using below code to covert all links in a page - Now i want this conversion to happen only for certain parts of page and not for complete page. I am sure this can be done to specific div tags

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {  
 $("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
 var value = $(this).attr('href');
 $(this).attr('href','<url>/pqr.php?'+value);
});
});</script>
```

Please suggest how can i achive this link conversion for specific div tags.

Example to explain problem statement - Consider following code snippet on which url conversion is required for only class="testclass"

```
  <div class="messageContent">     
    <article>
        <blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer ugc baseHtml">

            <div class="testclass">
                <a href="http://www.amzon.in" target="_blank" class="externalLink" rel="nofollow">Amazon 1</a>
            </div>


<i>eps</i><br>
<span style="text-decoration: underline"><b><i>How to avail this offer </i></b></span><br>
<i>Add product into the cart<br>
Login or register<br>
Enter your shipping details<br>
Make the Final Payment.</i><br>
<span style="text-decoration: underline"><span style="font-size: 12px"><b>link</b>       </span></span><br>
<a href="http://www.amzon.in" target="_blank" class="externalLink" rel="nofollow">Amazon 2</a>
                <div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
            </blockquote>
            </article>
     </div>
```

I want to convert only the first url (AMAZON 1) and not the second url (AMAZON 2)

Test snippet on js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bontp6jk/4/

Comment: `$(".testclass").each(function() { ..` comes to mind ?

Comment: $('.testclass').find("a[href^='http']").each(function() {... ?

Comment: Yes i thought of the exact same thing.. But could not get it to work as I am preety new in jquery :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bontp6jk/5/

Comment: Sounds like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678559/modify-href-link-dynamically-during-page-load#comment43772087_27678559 but improved question. Now just wondering the purpose of using multiple accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is first define the parent class and then for that class select all the link elements.

In jQuery you can use multiple selectors that works as follows:

```
$("#test")          // select div 'test'
$(".myClass")       // select class 'myClass'
$(".myClass #test") // select div 'test' in class 'myClass'
$("a")              // select all link elements
```

Therefore, what you need is the following: `$(".testclass a")` which selects all link elements in the class `.testclass`. Then you can use jQuery `.each()` function to do something with the link elements.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".testclass a").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(value);
    });
  });
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hawfxqzu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);            
            var value = $this.attr('href');
            if($this.closest('.testclass').length!==0){
            $this.attr('href','http://test.com/url.php?url=' + value + '&uid=test&origin=forum');
            $this.attr("target","_blank");    
}
        });
      });
```

Comment: This is not a good approach, because you'll loop over every available A-tag and then filter the results, instead of using the more precided selector first: $('.testclass').find("a[href^='http']")...

Comment: I can understand that by simply using selector $(".testclass a") can serve the purpose .. But here i am assuming that you might need to do some bit of code for other "anchor" too in future.

Comment: Totally agree with @axel.michel ..  $(".testclass a") will be way faster than $("a[href^='http']")  :) . but i think startedWith "^"  selector is used with a purpose here.